# Rifle with bayonet thrown like a javelin

Tags: military, war

I mean certainly there had to be a circumstance at one point where a soldier's only chance was to throw his rifle and somehow ended up winning? my searches have garnered no luck..

edit:for the 150 millionth time this question isn't asking how good of a tactic this would be, just simply asking if it's ever happened and been successful.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100253/discussion-on-question-by-datsunz1-rifle-with-bayonet-thrown-like-a-javelin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

15-ish years ago I actually read a book about Korean War with an account of a battle where the Americans were hard-pressed and an American thew his... rifle? carbine? like a spear, actually killing a Chinese soldier. The book MAY have been the classic "This Kind of War" by Fehrenbach... but since I'm not sure, I don't think this answer merits any valuable upvotes. :)

Comment: No!!!! this is 100% what i'm looking for!, i hope its non fiction im gonna dig into that.

Comment: It's non-fiction, very gritty and realistic for its time. Hope you find it.